# mockk, how to verify a specific exception is thrown

Tags: kotlin, mockk, mockk-verify

using mockk 1.9.3, junit 4

having a function which will report the exceptions for different conditions, need to test and verify the correct exception is reported.

```
class NetworkApi {
    fun actionAndLogExceptions(appContext: Context, optionalParams: Map<String, String>) {
        try {
            val result = doNetWorkCall(optionalParams)
            when (result) {
                TIMEOUT -> {throw SocketTimeoutException(...)}
                NETWORKERROR -> {throw HttpConnectionException(...)}
                JSON_EROOR -> {throw JSONException(...)}
                OK -> { handleResponce()}
            }
            
        } catch (ex: Throwable) {
            System.out.println("+++ !!! exp:" + ex.toString())
            ErrorReportManager.logHandledException(ex)
        }
    }

    internal fun doNetWorkCall(optionalParams: Map<String, String>): String {
        ... ...
    }
}

object ErrorReportManager {
    fun logHandledException(ex: Throwable) {
        ... ...
    }
}
```

the test

```
    @Test
    fun test_actionAndLogExceptions_report_exception() {
        val networkApiSpy = spyk(NetworkApi::class)
        every { networkApiSpy.doNetWorkCall(any(), any()) } returns JSON_EROOR. //<== test case one
        mockkStatic(ErrorReportManager::class)
        val spyApp = spyk(application)

        networkApiSpy.actionAndLogExceptions(spyApp, HashMap())

        // this any(JSONException::class) does not compile 
        io.mockk.verify(exactly = 1) {ErrorReportManager.logHandledException(any(JSONException::class))} //<===
        
        //how to verify that here the JSONException
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Raibaz help

```
verify {
    ErrorReportManager.logHandledException(ofType(JSONException::class))
} 
verify {
    ErrorReportManager.logHandledException(match { it is JSONException })
} 
val slot = slot<Throwable>()
verify {
    ErrorReportManager.logHandledException(capture(slot))
} 
assertTrue(slot.captured is JSONException)
```